# SVG not visible in Mac Safari

Tags: css, svg, safari

I have created an svg and use it in `<svg><use xlink="#id"></use></svg>`.

It's ok in all browsers except Mac Safari.

[here's a link](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/0dp081ky/).

```
<svg class="progress" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 55.917 59.667">
    <use xlink:href="#progressSVG"></use>   
</svg>
```

---

```
<svg version="1.1" class="hide" x="0px" y="0px" width="55.917px" height="59.667px" viewBox="0 0 55.917 59.667" enable-background="new 0 0 55.917 59.667" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="progressSVG">
    <polygon points="1.083,35.417 20.083,16.583 27.249,23.336 46.313,4.999 43.208,2.042 55.917,0 53.802,12.167 50.521,9.385 27.458,32.792 20.25,25.667 6.208,40.292 "/>
    <rect x="0" y="44.667" width="14.917" height="15"/>
    <rect x="20.62" y="37.667" width="14.917" height="22"/>
    <rect x="40.537" y="27.667" width="14.917" height="32"/>
</g>
</svg>


.hide{
display:none;
}
.progress{
width:150px;
height:150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that safari has a bug where `<use>` only works if the thing being pointed to is in the same SVG fragment e.g.

```css
.progress{
width:150px;
height:150px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="progress" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 55.917 59.667">
  <defs>
  <g id="progressSVG">
    <polygon points="1.083,35.417 20.083,16.583 27.249,23.336 46.313,4.999 43.208,2.042 55.917,0 53.802,12.167 50.521,9.385 27.458,32.792 20.25,25.667 6.208,40.292 "/>
    <rect x="0" y="44.667" width="14.917" height="15"/>
    <rect x="20.62" y="37.667" width="14.917" height="22"/>
    <rect x="40.537" y="27.667" width="14.917" height="32"/>
</g>
    </defs>
<use xlink:href="#progressSVG"></use>   
</svg>
```